# How can you decrement a static data member from inside a const member function?

Tags: c++, static-members, function-qualifier

```
class AccountManager
{
private:
    Account accountlist[100];
    int *accountNumber;
    Account* SuperVipAccount; 
    static int ManagerNumber;
public
    int getManagerNumber() const;
};
```

I have a class like this, and I want to use decrement operator in "getManagerNumber" to let ManagerNumber minus one, what should I do?

Comment: Why would you do something you explicitly disallow doing in the declaration???

Comment: but really why have you specified `getManagerNumber()` as `const`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ManagerNumber` is a `static` member of the `AccountManager` (shared across the class and not per object), so you can **decrement it** very well.
Method's `const` correctness doesn't apply to the `static` members.

```
int getManagerNumber() const
{
  -- ManagerNumber;  // ok
  return ManagerNumber;
}
```

Comment: AccountManager::AccountManager()
    {
        ManagerNumber = 0;
        this -> SuperVipAccount = NULL;
        *(this -> accountNumber) = 0; 
    } I got "undefined reference to `AccountManager::ManagerNumber'"

Comment: @Laurent `static int ManagerNumber` declares the variable but doesn't define it. Put `int AccountManager::ManagerNumber = 0;`, or whatever the initial value is going to be, in the cpp file. I usually put it near the top, after the includes but before the function definitions.

Comment: @Laurent: if you do "*(this -> accountNumber) = 0;" without initializing your pointer, then you have undefined behavior (next to what littleadv already remarked)

Answer (score 0):

```
class AccountManager
{
static int ManagerNumber;
}

AccountManager::ManagerNumber=0;

 int AccountManager::getManagerNumber()
    {
    return --ManagerNumber;
    }
```